# A clean way to organize and load files with subclasses

Tags: python

I have a parent class that provides abstract functions for manipulating hardware, and a directory full of classes that subclass this parent class, and provide hardware-specific implementation (e.g. x86 functions, ARM functions...).  I am looking for a Pythonic way to import the files in the directory, and instantiate them.

At the moment the parent class is in the top level directory, and the files with the child classes in a subdirectory.  This can be changed, for style or ease of implementation.

Is it preferable to load all the hardware-specific classes in the subdirectory by defining a list of them in a configuration file, and iterating over that to import them?  Or would it be better (more Pythonic) to do it automatically with importlib?  Or does it not matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a folder structure like this one:

```
.
├── arm (i kept this one empty, see similar x86 folder)
├── hal
│   ├── flags.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── registers.py
├── x86
│   ├── flags.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── registers.py
└── 8086.py
```

Put your ARM modules inside `arm` folder, x86 modules in `x86` folder and so on.

Put your hardware parent classes in a parallel folder, represented in the tree by the `hal` folder. Notice that you probably have specific modules for each arch (in respective folder) with the same names of generic modules in the `hal` folder (but this is only a suggestion).

Build your hardware in a file such as `8086.py` in the parent folder.
Sample of `8086.py` code:

```
from x86 import Ax, Bx, ZF # only the classes you need

ax = Ax()
bx = Bx()

# build your remaining CPU...
```

Sample of `hal/flags.py`:

```
class ZeroFlag():
    pass
```

Sample of `hal/registers.py`:

```
class Register:
    pass
```

Sample of `hal/__init__.py`:

```
from hal.registers import Register
from hal.flags import ZeroFlag
```

Sample of `x86/flags.py`

```
from hal import ZeroFlag

class ZF(ZeroFlag):
    pass
```

Sample of `x86/registers.py`

```
from hal import Register

class Ax(Register):
    pass

class Bx(Register):
    pass
```

Sample of `x86/__init__.py`

```
from .registers import *
from .flags import *
```

Now in each arch the specific modules can inherit and customize generic classes from `hal`. At top folder modules, you import those specifics to build your CPU or whatever hardware you are making.

Notice the importance of `__init__.py` files. they turn the folders into packages. `__init__` also run on package import, allowing you to specify all the package modules you want to make available to importer. Note also that this list does not force the importer to import all the names. It can specify only the wanted ones.

If you have lots and lots of files you can place code in the `__init__.py` files to automate the imports, instead of writing them all by hand.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea of dividing the sub classes int different files and importing only what you need is very pythonic. Consider using a `__init__.py` file in your subclasses' folder with an `import SubClass1, SubClass2, SubClass3, ...`-command in it. Then you can just say in the `main.py`:

```
import folderOfSubClasses
```

Then the `__init__.py` file will be executed and you have the expected result.

I hope I could help you!