# Module can't be found when called from outside

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a multiple sub-modules python project. For example, "myproject" which has two submodules namely "submodule1" and "submodule2".

Project structure

```
Example1/
|-- submodule1/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- hello.py
...
|-- submodule2/
|   |-- __init__.py
...
```

And I have a `hello.py` in `submodule1` which has the following content:

```
import datetime

def greeting():
    print("hello world! - " + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

The content for `submodule1`'s `__init__.py` is:

```
def main():
    import hello
    hello.greeting()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am able to import `hello.py` and call `greeting()` function successfully here.

Now, I installed `submodule1` as a package to python, and then created `submodule2`, and tried to call `submodule1` from `submodule2` by putting following code in `__init__.py` from `submodule2`:

```
import submodule1

def main():
    submodule1.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It fails with this message:

```
....in main submodule1.main()
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hello'
```

I think `hello` shouldn't be exposed to outside, how am I able to let my `submodule1` works? I'm using python3

========

setup.py is:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

with open('requirements.txt') as f:
    requirements = f.read().splitlines()

__version__ = "0.0.2"

setup(
    version=__version__
    name = "mymodules",
    packages = find_packages(exclude=['tests', '*.tests', '*.tests.*']),
    install_requires=requirements,
)
```

Comment: How did you install it? With a `setup.py`?

Comment: I think he just made a package (by arranging the structure that way) and the errors are thrown when importing the package.

Comment: Yes @Felk, I use `setup.py` to install `submodule1`

Comment: Can we see it? It needs to specific the modules, either manually or with setuptools' find_packages()

Comment: I updated the post by add `setup.py`

Comment: @Felk I updated my answer, not sure the problem is with setup, to begin with. Also `Example1` needs its own  `__init__.py` if it is to be a package.

Comment: When you `import submodule`, the `__name__` isn't `__main__`. This is only true when `submodule` is invoked as a main module. If you move `import hello` outside of `def main()`, it should work as intended.

Comment: @progmatico `Example1` just a project name, it's not a module by it self. and @alvits , what do you mean `move import hello outside of def main()`? it is out of main already.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
def main():
    from .submodule1 import hello 
    # or from Example1.submodule1 import hello
        hello.greeting()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It is not finding `hello` because it is not in `submodule2` folder. You have to give the interpreter the relative path inside the package, or the absolute path in the package. This only works with the `from ...` import syntax form.

Omitting the package name can be useful if you have lots of imports and later want to change your package name.

Edit:

This is from the point of view of the code inside the `Example1` package, if you turn it into one. That is, this is the way code inside the package `Example1`, in some submodule, can refer code inside other `Example1` submodule, with submodules placed in different folders also with their `__init__.py` inside. This is insider knowledge, but it is to be used from inside the package `Example1`. When you are outside, importing the package `Example1`, you can import all the names you want to be seen from the outside (in the importer) in the Example1 `__init__.py` file.

So I see two different questions here:

How do I refer code from submodule to submodule, with both being inside the same package (do like I said), and how do I export names inside my package to outsiders importing my package (import the names in the package `_init__.py` so you can write things like `from MyPackage import Class1, Class2, other_name` or even `*` - use an `__all__` list to control those names).

Also I don't understand why you call submodules to your submodules and then try to install one of them as an isolated package and use it like that. Aren't they part of your `Example1` package? If they were isolated packages they shouldn't refer the others...

Stated like this, this may look confusing, actually packages aren't the simplest concept to explain, but it is not that difficult either.

See a clean example I made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47499730/a-clean-way-to-organize-and-load-files-with-subclasses/47501913#47501913) on how to organize classes as a package and use them inside the package (insider knowledge of course). Pay attention to the `__init__.py` files content as it is similar to what you want to do to make names available outside your package (no inside knowledge except for the importable names).

2nd Edit:

So I trace some source of confusion between me and OP to this:
everything I said above applies to [import packages](https://packaging.python.org/glossary/#term-import-package) while OP is thinking in terms of [distribution packages](https://packaging.python.org/glossary/#term-distribution-package). Not surprisingly, even the glossary refers this confusion as a real possibility.

Did you try

```
from . import hello
```

in the `submodule1` import package `__init__.py`, instead of `import hello`? That should use the `submodule1` namespace.

3rd edit:

Your errors might happen because after setting up imports, running with sucess still depends on how you are running the code (I mean from where you import the whole thing), which is usually the package parent folder. If you try to start code from an inside point it can still fail despite being correct (sorry the incoherence).

Even that can be solved with absolute imports but that requires Example1 to become a package, because you have dependencies between the submodules (actually subpackages).

And that leads me to another point:

An import package can contain nested import packages (subpackages), and also modules. That makes it adequate for any project. That means also there is an outer package that contains everything. That is your project. Make releases of that outer package, your project.

Suppose you say "submodules have to be installed separately". Fine. Assuming they are independent, make them packages (they are packages already). Release them separately as above.

Or,

to me they look related, it looks some "submodules" depend on others.

You also say "submodules underneath can be responded by different developers". That is no excuse. It looks to me as a common code base, put them all in version control (you did, didn't you). Tag the files in release points, or put releases in their own branch. Make it all a single package. Release that package.

Otherwise I think you are setting up for chaos. And you are trying to use release packages to control it. How do you keep a log of what version works with what version of another submodule. And if you put the sources of different submodules together for test, they will conflict (override) previously installed submodules in your system.

Also your package will have a single entry point, either a simple import of it or some main hook to run a main function perhaps, not several possible entry points from each "submodule".

I hope that this helps solving your problem, not exactly your error.

Comment: I don't think that's the way when we are using any 3rd module, for example if we want print `timestamp`, just need import `datetime`, don't have to know  the path, and we don't have a path also. I tried `from submodule1 import hello`, the error is "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.submodule1'; '__main__' is not a package".

Comment: If I uninstall `submodule1` it will reported `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'submodule1'` immediately, so I believe module importing is good, but it tried to resolve `hello` from current scope which is `submodule2`, not in `submodule1`.

Comment: I updated your code to `submodule1`, it reported me `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.submodule1'; '__main__' is not a package`, but if I updated to `submodule2`, it works, which means by this way, `hello.greeting()` is able to be called, but it also means I have to expose `hello` to the world which is very not make sense, assume if `hello` will calls to another function named `hello1`, then it will fail again.

Comment: @user3593261, there is some confusion here, we were thinking differently. I tried to elaborate my rationale. See my edit, and my other example, hope that helps.

Comment: \@progmatico You can think they are separate function modules, `Example1` just the project name. Submodules underneath can be responded by different developers and be installed separatly. In this example, I'm trying to  simulate this scenario, but in real project, each submodule might have it's own `setup.py`, so that means they will be packaged to different release packages just like two separate projects. I'm trying to hide detail structure in one module to an other one.

Comment: I tried `from . import hello` in `submodule1` it doesn't work and said: `ImportError: cannot import name 'hello'`

Answer (score 1):

For Python3.5 and assuming you want to install packages submodule1 and submodule2, if not please mention how you intend to use them: This is how the project is structured

```
    (2005env) python@python:~/2005env/Example1$ tree
.
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
├── submodule1
│   ├── hello.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── submodule2
    └── __init__.py

2 directories, 5 files
```

Placed setup.py outside both submodules, it can also be placed inside individual submodules to install them separately with a bit of change in directory structure and installation.

```
(2005env) python@python:~/2005env/Example1$ pip install -e .
Obtaining file:///home/python/2005env/Example1
Installing collected packages: submodule1
  Running setup.py develop for submodule1
Successfully installed submodule1
```

Now importing submodule2 in python3.5 from location outside project directory i.e. /home/python and project is in /home/python/2005env/Example1

```
(2005env) python@python:~$ python
Python 3.5.3 (default, Nov 23 2017, 11:34:05) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170406] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import submodule2
>>> dir(submodule2)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'main', 'submodule1']
>>> submodule2.main()
Hello World! - 2018-02-25 09:03:32
>>> dir(submodule2.submodule1)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'greeting', 'hello', 'main']


Python 3.5.3 (default, Nov 23 2017, 11:34:05) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170406] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from submodule1 import greeting
>>> greeting()
Hello World! - 2018-02-25 09:26:14
```

In **init**.py of submodule1 I have imported hello as well as greetings hence those are available as attributes

```
(2005env) python@python:~/2005env/Example1$ cat submodule1/__init__.py 
from . import hello
from .hello import greeting


def main():
    hello.greeting()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

setup.py is same as yours with find_packages but name if submodule1 instead of mymodules

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work as I said in the previous post, `from . import hello` will failed by `ImportError: cannot import name 'hello'`, not sure if it because I'm under windows.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I figured it out. I can't put

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

in the `__init__`, it never work, which caused me try to run it directly and failed by `ImportError: cannot import name 'hello'`. When `__init__` is `__main__`, it cannot import substuffs, but it works if called from outside, for example, from submodule2, `submodule1.main()` still available. So this issue looks doesn't impact to user now. Thanks for `@progmatico`, you answers help me a lot to understand how those functions work together, very appreciate!

Comment: You are welcome, great that you spot the specific reason for your trouble. `__init__.py` will run on package import only, and if the package is to be imported (that's the usual scenario), the `if`main condition will never be true. I actually missed that in your code, but actually that's also what I meant when I say that there is usually one single entry point. Those `if`s make sense when you want to run a module for import also as a script (say to run tests, although not the way to organize tests in a package), not to enter inside your package code from arbitraire places.