# How to properly import parent module/other submodules in Python

Tags: python

Apologies if that titles a little confusing.

Basically, if I have a submodule that refers any other package (without the full module reference, i.e import foo.bar rather than import project.foo.bar) and produce a package graph using pyreverse, then pyreverse doesn't show that the submodule is using foo.bar.

For example, if I have the following package structure

```
parent/
--__init__.py
--parent_example.py
--sub/
----__init__.py
----sub_example.py
```

Where the file sub_example.py contains `from parent_example import foo`

it produces the following diagram when ran with the command `pyreverse parent -o png`

[image]

However if you import using an absolute path `from parent.parent_example import foo` and run the same command, it outputs what you would expect

[image]

So my question is as follows - if I am importing a module form another package, should I be using an absolute path like in example two (from the root of what is assumed to be the most top level package - in the example case, the parent package), or should I be importing like I am in the first example?

I understand that this might be seen as asking for opinions - I'd like to clarify that I'm looking for the python recommended way (most standard practice, or PEP if it exists) to handle imports

Cheers

Comment: I think you are thinking too much as objects (so parent, children). See modules as unrelated. Naming is just convenience. Use `import parent` in `parent.sub`. Every children should know the name of the parent.

Answer (score 1):

"Where the file sub_example.py contains `from parent_example import foo`"

Above should not even work with the module locations shown.

"However if you import using an absolute path `from parent.parent_example import foo`"

That is a relative import, that specifies a full absolute path inside the package (that is path from the root of the package).
Everything ok with that form.

The first form should read

```
from ..parent_example import foo
```

All those files belong (are inside) `parent` package. And so you can specify the imports with relative imports, `from <put.your.path> import some_bar` or `from <.your.path> import some_bar` or `from <..your.path> import some_bar`, and so on... in any of the modules inside `parent`.

Whether you use always the full relative path or always partial relative paths is a matter of personal choice.

Usually it makes sense to omit the name of the `parent` package
 as it isn't needed and so you can change its name without touching the code inside.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48890084/module-cant-be-found-when-called-from-outside/) might be useful to you