# Accessing lib modules from everywhere?

Tags: python, python-import

Normally I have to do in every file something like this :

```
 import os, sys
 sys.path.extend(['lib', '../lib'])
```

Is there a easy way. So I dont have to do this in every file ?

So that I can simply do :

```
 from abc import *
```

---

cant understand how this work... https://docs.python.org/2/library/pkgutil.html#module-pkgutil

but probably some `__init__.py` trick may work !

Comment: Is the code in lib code you have written or third party packages?

Comment: i have written the lib code

Comment: Do you know about organizing code with regular import packages (those using `__init__.py` inside folders)?

Comment: Something similar to  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47499730/a-clean-way-to-organize-and-load-files-with-subclasses/47501913#47501913)

Comment: You can just place an `__init__.py` inside your `libs` or utils, whatever, and start organizing your reusable code there. Then you import things from your runnable modules in the outer folder.

Comment: i know init.py , but dont know how syspath behaves for libs outside of the current dir hierarchy

Comment: Ah ok. Python just searches all the paths listed there. Only be careful with search order. Current dir (where the script was called to execute) is searched first and can override modules in other locations.

Comment: so what do i put in init.py

Comment: You can leave it empty. Just put `__init__.py` files in every folder and sub folder of your package so that internal modules can reach each other with relative imports. Remember that execution entry point should stay out of the libs package, in another module. Import your package or names from there. You can also put code that runs on import inside __init__.py, for initialization or to further managed names available to import. But in many cases the `__init__.py` can remain with no problems.

Comment: I am referring to access code that is always inside your libs folder. Were you asking about extending to scattered folders in arbitrary places outside your project structure? That is a different problem I was not commenting about.

Comment: yes.. outside of the current dir

Comment: Do as you were doing (or use PYTHONPATH ) to add absolute paths to your external lib folders. Maybe gather the paths in some central file and configure your sys.path from a module you can import (run) from all modules with a single statement... You may get trouble if you use relative paths, depending on running  module relative locations to each other.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).

> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the variable sys.path. sys.path is initialized from these locations:
>
> - The directory containing the input script (or the current directory when no file is specified).
> - `PYTHONPATH` (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
> - The installation-dependent default.

Comment: thanks .. subquestion ...that probably wont work well... if I have many projects with their own libs dir and  a shared lib dir, right ? too many dirs in the path and if I relocate the prj have to update it